# pax, invalid replacement string option

Tags: regular-expression, string, pax

I'm having a little trouble understanding what's happening in a Perl script that uses `pax`.

**Background:** Feeding a `.tgz` file to `pax` and unpacking to get a folder full of files.

**This is the thing I don't understand:**

`pax -r -z -s '/.*\\//directory\\//p' -f $input_path/$tgz`

Where `$input_path` is a scalar variable in Perl containing a path and `$tgz` is another scalar variable containing the name of the `.tgz` file.

So `-r` for reading makes sense, `-z` for unzipping is fine. The `-s` and `-f` flags confuse me. I get the following error:
`pax: Invalid replacement string option /.*\\//directory\\//p`.

**How I think the flags work:**

`-f`, as this doesn't seem to be the problem. This is just where to put the files.

`-s`, string replacement to modify the names of the file contained in the `.tgz` file.

Can anyone demystify the `/.*\\//directory\\//p` part, as I don't really get what's going on here with all the escape slashes, `\` and the `p` must do something but I have no idea what?

Comment: The syntax is `-s /old/new/[gp]/`, where `old` is a basic regular expression (cf. `re_format(7)`).  The `p` flag makes `pax` print successful substitution to `stderr`.  However, `.*\\//directory\\ ` is not a valid BRE.  It's hard to tell whether the problem comes from the original script or from your attempt at obfuscation.  You also claim you found this is in a `perl` script, which doesn't make sense, either.

Comment: @SatoKatsura So it's, `old` = `.` (here, so what does the wildcard do? all that is here?) and `new` = `directory`? I'm not sure what you meant by [gp] or BRE. In the `perl` script it is enclosed within back-ticks and then `;`.

Comment: If you use the `pax` provided by `star`, you get this error message: `pax: Bad substitute option 'd'.` which is a result from incorrect backslash quoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pax parses `/.*\\//directory\\//p` as:

- `/` is the separator character.
- `.*\\` is the regular expression, matching any string ending with a backslash (backslash quotes the next character).
- `/` separates the regular expression from the replacement text.
- `/` ends the replacement text.
- `directory\\//p` is trailing garbage.

Evidently, you meant to use the backslashes to protect the slashes so that they're part of the regex rather than separators. For a shell script, there are extra backslashes in there (but they may be due to the fact that this is happening in a perl script, more on this later). There's also something wrong with the slashes. If you want to remove `any/leading/prefix/up/to/directory` from the paths, then it should be

```
pax -r -z -s '/.*\/directory\///p' -f "$input_path/$tgz"
```

It would be easier to read with a different separator. Then you wouldn't need to escape slashes.

```
pax -r -z -s '!.*/directory/!!p' -f "$input_path/$tgz"
```

---

All this assumes that the command is a *shell* command. You mention a Perl script; Perl would add its own layer of quoting, so what to write depends on how the string is inserted in the Perl script. The use of `$input_path/$tgz` is definitely problematic because it's interpolating a string into a shell script, so that string will be parsed as a shell snippet instead of a file name.

If the shell command is between double quotes or backticks, then the backslashes do need doubling. There's still the problem of the misplaces slash. Here's a way to write this in Perl:

```
my $quoted_file_name = quotemeta("$input_path/$tgz");
system("pax -r -z -s '!.*/directory/!!p' -f $quoted_file_name");
```

If you're using `system` then you should use the list form instead to avoid quoting issues by not invoking an intermediate shell.

```
system('pax', '-r', '-z', '-s', '!.*/directory/!!p', '-f', "$input_path/$tgz");
```